# What kind of sill cap/threshold is this?

Tags: doors, air-quality, weatherstripping, threshold

I'm fighting some air infiltration from under my exterior doors. I've noticed that this sill cap / threshold is unlike any I can find in stores, as it has an indented channel in the middle. Is something meant to go in there to better seal to the door bottom?

[image: sill cap]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing parts there. No threshold has an open channel like that. At a minimum there would be a rubber strip across it. Most have a solid cap over that area with captive adjustment screws in it.

You can't really just replace a modern threshold with generic parts. It's part of a proprietary door system and it's fairly locked in place. Find the manufacturer and order the correct parts.

[image]

<sub>[source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fiiitl.ac.in%2Findex.php%2Fpersonnel%2Fdr-amit-kumar-singh%3Fk%3Dm-d-adjustable-36-l-x-4-9-16-cc-Jdk8nDt6&psig=AOvVaw2zl-z0cuZneod1S_mP1GeI&ust=1705418946278000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBUQjhxqFwoTCMC3iuja34MDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAI)</sub>